# Display Google Map after entering address?

Tags: google-maps

Trying to find an easy way to do the following:

1) Visitor enters their address in a form field
2) Google map display's their address on the page

Does not seem to be an easy way to accomplish this in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for geofield gmap module, it have the option same like your requirement. See the below screenshot and also easy to configure.

[Geofield Gmap](https://drupal.org/project/geofield_gmap) allow to use a google map v3 map to **input a location**.

A **quick text input + geocode** allow you to specify an address.

You can also drag and drop the marker to narrow the position.

[image]

Geofield Gmap require geofield.

[Geofield](https://drupal.org/project/geofield) is a module for storing geographic data in Drupal 7. It supports all geo-types (points, lines, polygons, multitypes etc.)